# Find number of recently added database rows in Asp.Net Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a stats page on my website that shows how many rows have been added to a specific table in the last X minutes.

This is the first thing I tried:

```
int games = db.GameLogs.Where(t => t.GameEnded > DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Count();
```

I get this ugly error:

[image]

This is the second thing I tried:

```
var games = db.GameLogs.FromSqlRaw("select count(*) from mtgbattles.gamelogs  where gameended > now() - interval 1 minute");
```

I get the error:

> InvalidOperationException: The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

The query works fine in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving date calculation out of request:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1); // maybe `DateTime.UtcNow`
int games = db.GameLogs
    .Where(t => t.GameEnded > dt)
    .Count();
```

As for `FromSqlRaw` - currently it has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations), including :

> - The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type.

So your select statement should include all fields for `GameLogs` to make `FromSqlRaw` work.

Comment: In general it seems like putting functions in a fluent EF sql call always causes problems. This is the second time it's bitten me. Your suggestion works great, thanks.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky was glad to help. Also there is [SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffMinute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffminute?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions_DateDiffMinute_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_DateTime_System_DateTime_) but they should not work for MySQL I assume)

Comment: MS needs to reconsider their SQL Server licensing situation. I have to use dumpster SQL because MSSQL costs 15k/core. As a shareholder, I guess it's good. But it's not a way to hold onto the future.